# Looking for a way to concatenate two fields on the fly when defining a FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I was looking for some way to concatenate two fields on the fly when defining a FeatureCollection.  Perhaps something using some combination of .select, .setMulti or .cat but haven't been able to determine what the syntax would be.  I was hoping to avoid mapping across the Features as it is a very very large FetureCollection.  So hoping for something along the lines of (this obviously doesn't work, but for illustration):

`var myFC = ee.FeatureCollection('users/path/mytable').select(['FIELD1', 'FIELD2'], ee.FeatureCollection.setMulti(FIELD1.cat(FIELD2)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was hoping to avoid mapping across the Features as it is a very very large FetureCollection.

There is no reason to avoid mapping because of the size of the collection.

```
var myFC = ee.FeatureCollection('users/path/mytable')
  .map(function (feature) {
    return feature.set('FIELD12',
      feature.getString('FIELD1')
        .cat(' ')
        .cat(feature.getString('FIELD2')));
  });
```

This will work fine. There isn't a way to fundamentally improve on the performance of this — other than exporting the result to an asset so it can be indexed, which is only a benefit if you want to sort, filter, or join on the concatenation.

Comment: Thank you, this is good to know.  However, I tried the above and received the error "When Element.set() is passed multiple arguments, there must be an even number of them."  I think it's something about the two .get need to be somehow combined?  While we're at it, how would I also add a space between the two fields when combining them?

Comment: @r_m Sorry, I made a mistake when writing the code. Of course there had to be a cat(). I've also shown adding a space.